# nginx return not working

Tags: nginx, centos, http

I'm trying to setup nginx server to response `204` or `200` for all `GET` requests.

I've changed following files 

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.default
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Added following code.
from this 

        `location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }`

to this 

     `location / {
                return 204;
        }`

I'm expecting status code `204` from this changes.
But I'm getting nginx default html page with status code `200` for all GET requests.

I've restarted `nginx` server after changes, even tried rebooting system.

Do I need to add `site-available`, even though I'm not using any host I want `204` from serverip as this instances are serving behind amazon `ELB`

Server Stack:

`ec2-  c3 large
OS - Centos 6.5
nginx version: nginx/1.0.15`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it in my on vps and it works. Could you show me what are new line of the log when you access it to your IP address? If you didn't see anything, you must open it via private browser or another browser.

I configured it in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ and put a name "0default" with contain:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    root            /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;


    location / {
        return 204;
    }
}
```